# Why System.getProperty("java.home") works different for Eclipse 3.4, 3.5, 3.6?

Tags: eclipse, java-home

I develop plugins (to be honest I started not so long time ago) and test my plugins on different Eclipses. I have Eclipse 3.4, 3.5, 3.6 installed.
in C:\Program Files\Java there are:

- jdk1.5.0_22
- jdk1.6.0_21
- jre1.5.0_22
- jre6

for all versions of Eclipses, in here (Windows -> Preferences -> Installed JREs) there is "jdk1.5.0_22" with the path "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.5.0_22"

---

So, can not figure out why for Eclipse 3.5 and 3.6 this

```
 System.getProperty("java.home")
```

prints

> C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.5.0_22\jre

but in Eclipse 3.4 it prints

> C:\Program Files\Java\jre6

Could anyone give me a glue which value is used by System.getProperty("java.home")?

Comment: Update: resolved, see my own answer!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here, there is explanation how to solve similar problem
http://tech.karolzielinski.com/m2eclipse-eclipse-is-running-in-a-jre-but-a-jdk-is-required
In my case it was enough to add -vm option to eclipse.ini file for Eclipse 3.4.

```
-vm
C:\Progra~1\Java\jdk1.5.0_22\jre\bin\javaw
```

Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 2):

You can check your Project Build Path:

Example:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

The java.home property returns the Java installation directory. In Windows, this is set either with the JAVA_HOME environmental variable or in the eclipse.ini file. It could be also given as a command parameter in the eclipse.exe.

You can read some instructions about running eclipse [here](http://ist.berkeley.edu/as-ag/tools/howto/install-eclipse-win.html).

Comment: The problem is that here http://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_How_do_I_run_Eclipse%3F it says  Eclipse DOES NOT consult the JAVA_HOME environment variable. And there is no -vm option in eclipse.ini files for all version (3.4, 3.5, 3.6), just verified.

Comment: "java.home" is a system property (http://www.mindspring.com/~mgrand/java-system-properties.htm), and, as I can guess, depends ONLY on installed version of Java. So, it is very strange that the its value is different on the same PC for different Eclipse versions.